# JS click event needs setTimeout to trigger click event

Tags: javascript, events, button, click, settimeout

I have a dialog with buttons on the left side and right side. This dialog is bound to several buttons out on the main body that saves attributes on the buttons so the dialog can be filled with the previous selection (so the states are saved).

```
arrayWithIds.forEach(function(id){
    var button= self.query('[value='+id+']', table1)[0];
    button.click(); 
});
```

The .click even triggers event handlers bound earlier to see if the user may press OK.
The right and left runs the same code but only the left buttons runs the click event.
However, with a timeout

```
arrayWithIds.forEach(function(id){
    var button= self.query('[value='+id+']', table1)[0];
    setTimeout(function(){
        button.click(); 
    },20);
});
```

It works just fine?

Comment: After investigatnig more, the event is raised on IE9 in IE8 document mode, but not in latest firefox.

Comment: After some more investigation in FF it seems to be because the button was disabled, tho I tried enabling it before .click();, still no work.